# mod_deflate with facebook share button not showing the share details?

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html #<<facebook share problem
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

i have a problem when i activate the mod_deflate [AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html] in .htaccess 
the share button works but no title ,no thumbnail ,no description ....
i tried and disabled it ,the sharing went fine , but i really need DEFLATE text/html.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only configuring mod_deflate in .htaccess?  Are there other mod_deflate parameters in httpd.conf?

I suggest you make sure all the formats used are correct. Also, try simple parameters.  Test only with`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html` first.  Then, go putting other formats.  Before the test, enable the mod_deflate log.

Below I put a sample Apache 2.2.x httpd.conf that I tested.  In it you can see how config the deflate log:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# example of how to compress ONLY html, plain text and xml #
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

# Don't compress binaries
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|iso|tar|bz2|sit|rar) no-gzip dont-vary

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|jpg|ico|png) no-gzip dont-vary

# Don't compress PDFs
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .pdf no-gzip dont-vary

# Don't compress flash files (only relevant if you host your own videos)
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .flv no-gzip dont-vary

# Netscape 4.X has some problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

# Setup custom deflate log
DeflateFilterNote Input instr
DeflateFilterNote Output outstr
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
LogFormat '"%r" %{outstr}n/%{instr}n %{ratio}n%%' DEFLATE
CustomLog logs/deflate_log DEFLATE
```

This sample I get of this site: [How To: Optimize Your Apache Site with Mod Deflate](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-optimize-your-apache-site-with-mod-deflate/)